# LanguageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HelpFileUK" ofType:@"rtf"]];

Tags: cocoa, url-routing

```
resourcePath is find but the string has a lot of characters     (clihupjqutbndlevnqrhmwweound) that maybe should not be there.
```

LanguageUrl = (null)

I check the sandbox but find no hints.
Because the URL = (null) the rtf files can't be found.
The .rtf files are (visible) in the project navigator
Do I have to set something in the plist?
I have the latest update Mojave and Xcode.

```
-(void)showText {
NSLog(@"showText");
NSURL *LanguageUrl;
NSAttributedString *helpFileString;
NSString *resourcePath;
NSLog(@"taalIndex = %li", (long)self.taalIndex);
/*
resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]   pathForResource:@"HelpFileUK" ofType:@"rtf"];
NSLog(@" resourcePath = %@", resourcePath);
LanguageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HelpFileUK" ofType:@"rtf"]];
NSLog(@" URLuk = %@", LanguageUrl);
*/

switch(self.taalIndex) {
    case 1:     //  united kingdom
        resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]     pathForResource:@"HelpFileUK" ofType:@"rtf"];
        NSLog(@" resourcePath = %@", resourcePath);
        LanguageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HelpFileUK" ofType:@"rtf"]];
        NSLog(@" URLuk = %@", LanguageUrl);
        break;
    case 2:     //  the netherlands
        resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HelpTxtNL" ofType:@"rtf"];
        NSLog(@" resourcePath = %@", resourcePath);
        LanguageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:resourcePath];
        NSLog(@" URLnl = %@", LanguageUrl);
        break;
}

helpFileString = [[NSAttributedString    alloc]initWithURL:LanguageUrl options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:NULL error:nil];
NSLog(@" helpFileString = %@", helpFileString);

[self.helpView replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,0) withRTF:[helpFileString RTFFromRange:NSMakeRange(0,[helpFileString length]) documentAttributes:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}]];
```

}

LanguageUrl = (null)

Answer (score 1):

That's a very common mistake. You are using the wrong API. On file system level you have to use `fileURLWithPath:`

```
LanguageUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HelpFileUK" ofType:@"rtf"]];
```

But why not much simpler

```
LanguageUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] urlForResource:@"HelpFileUK" withExtension:@"rtf"];
```

And please name all variables with starting lowercase letter.